# Create folder/image automatically when image captured

Tags: android, android-camera

When I capture an image, It creates a folder in the gallery and put that image inside that folder. But it takes some time to load (the new folder and the pictures), more or less 1 minute. Why is that? Is there a way to lessen that creation time or just automatically create that folder and put the captured images inside it after taking a photo?

```
OnClick..

String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

Intent intent_cam = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                    
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "App Photos");

if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {       

    imagesFolder.mkdirs();          
    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "App_" + timeStamp + ".png");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);         
    intent_cam.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);    
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); 
    startActivityForResult(intent_cam, 1);          
}

else if (imagesFolder.exists()) {

    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "App_" + timeStamp + ".png");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
    intent_cam.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    startActivityForResult(intent_cam, 1);    
}
```

Comment: Better you can do that folder existence check in onResume() .

Comment: Please explain, **completely and precisely**, what "load" means in "it takes some time to load".

Comment: @CommonsWare - to appear in the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MediaScannerConnection` to have the `MediaStore` scan the file. Beyond that, it is up to the implementation of the gallery app, which you do not control.